# how to load list values with checkbox selection in dropdown list

Tags: java, spring

${SFNameList1.name}
            
             
            ${SFNameList1.name}
            
              
            ${SFNameList1.name}
            
              
            ${SFNameList1.name}
            
             
            
            
            
            
            Doctor Name

```
        <div>
        <label class="Date7">Product Name &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form:select path="ProductNameList"  id="product" name="productName"  style="width: 250px; margin-left: 100px;height: 37px;margin-top: 10px;">
                <option value="" label="--- Select Product Name ---" />
                <c:forEach  var="ProductNameList" items="${ProductNameList}" varStatus="loop">
            <option value="${ProductNameList.productCode}">${ProductNameList.productName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
        </label>     
        </div>

        <div id="Button" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
              <button id = "button1" class="Button_Design" onClick="view();">PROCEED</button>
```

Comment: I'm really not sure about what you want here. Could you search for an image or something that shows the desired behaviour?

Comment: in these code i have to load products name with checkbox selection in list.how to do this